# Emacs: Differentiate markdown cells in Emacs IPython Notebook (EIN)

Tags: emacs, ipython, jupyter-notebook

How can I change the text color or the cell background for a markdown cell in [Emacs IPython Notebook](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-ipython-notebook)?

Text in markdown cells is the same color as code.  This makes it difficult to navigate the page.  I can't easily differentiate what cells are code and which are annotations.

As a workaround, I've been using code cells with comments.  The comments (in my theme) are green and they stand out nicely.  But this makes the final notebook look disorganized.

Comment: the different type cells don't seem to have different face definition

Answer (score 0):

You *might* be able to achieve this with themes in [polymode](https://polymode.github.io/concepts/), but there is a post over on the Emacs Stackexchange suggesting that this isn't how themese work and that [it may only be possible for the background](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/43674/different-themes-in-different-modes).